# SMO unable to find table from name in T4

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4, smo

I'm writting a simple t4 template to create scripts for my SQL Server 2008 database. This lines of code:

```
1 myDataBase.Refresh();
2 var tableName = "sometable";
3 Table t = myDataBase.Tables[tableName];
```

are resulting in `t == null`.  The "sometable" is in my database and is not mispelled, the connection works fine.  Debbuging the template and returning the execution point to the line 3 populates the `t` variable correctly.  Someone can help me to undestand what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a belated response but other developers may find it useful.

```
 myDataBase.Refresh();
 var tableName = "sometable";
 **myDataBase.Tables.Refresh();**
 Table t = myDataBase.Tables[tableName];
```

Comment: I don't see this bug in Visual Studio 2013.  I guess is version specific.